# Improve app speed with `pickerInput` size options

Tags: shiny, shinywidgets

I 'm developping a Shiny App with the `shinyWidgets` package for doing my `selectInput`.
I have many modalities for the inputs variable which cause some bugs.
I reduced the size of the `picker` (size argument) and if possible show only 10 first options of variables and activate the liveSearch option. But not seems to work ...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue1", 
    label = "somevalue1",         
    choices = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE,
    selected = NULL,
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE,
      size = 10,
      `live-search` = TRUE
    )
  ),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "somevalue2", 
    label = "somevalue2",         
    choices = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE,
    selected = NULL,
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE,
      size = 10,
      `live-search` = TRUE
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "somevalue1",
      choices = 1:1000
    )
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$somevalue1))
      choices <- which(input$somevalue1 %in% 1:1000)
    else
      choices <- 1:1000

    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "somevalue2",
      choices = choices
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this example I want to show only the first 10 value (but could find others if I search them). I want to remove the scroll bar, is it possible ?

Comment: Hi Mostafa, please add a min reprex

Comment: Hi Eli, it's done you can check update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to the ui:

```
,tags$head(
    tags$style(
        '.inner.open {
            overflow-y: hidden !important;
        }'
    )
)
```

Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
    pickerInput(
        inputId = "somevalue1", 
        label = "somevalue1",         
        choices = NULL,
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = NULL,
        options = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE,
            size = 10,
            `live-search` = TRUE
        )
    ),
    pickerInput(
        inputId = "somevalue2", 
        label = "somevalue2",         
        choices = NULL,
        multiple = TRUE,
        selected = NULL,
        options = list(
            `actions-box` = TRUE,
            size = 10,
            `live-search` = TRUE
        )
    ),
    tags$head(
        tags$style(
            '.inner.open {
                overflow-y: hidden !important;
            }'
        )
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        updatePickerInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = "somevalue1",
            choices = 1:1000
        )
    })

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$somevalue1))
            choices <- which(input$somevalue1 %in% 1:1000)
        else
            choices <- 1:1000

        updatePickerInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = "somevalue2",
            choices = choices
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Sure, Chrome DevTools is your friend. Very useful for playing around with CSS.